# Multiple line-block elements

Tags: html, css

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width: 200px;">Sidebar</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">Content</div> 
</div>
```

My goal is to display the divs and the list items horizontally. What style do I set on the second div with the list items to force its width to fill the rest of the screen (screen width - 200px, width of first div)? I can't use a specific px value, since that would break with different screen sizes.

Also, when there is enough content in the second div to wrap (e.g. unordered list items styled with display: inline-block), instead of wrapping, it displays the divs vertically.

This also doesn't work in IE9 compatibility mode, even when using the *display: inline hack.

This would be trivial to implement using a table, but I'd like to do it "right", if possible. I would also prefer not to use float.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It feels like a hack to float the left div, and then adjust the margin on the right div to separate them. I'll use it, since it's common practice and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I would recommend not using inline:block and trying a float solution instead. also may need to use clearfix on the parent div.

It's not quite clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Float does not work for me. In the right div I have an unordered list that uses display:inline-block to display the list items horizontally.

Comment: Float is not any more of a hack than inline block. And since there really is no right way to do it, use float, which is the best hack. I never use inline block and i dont think you should either. Iirc, it is unsupported in older IEs

Comment: Floating works in IE9 Compatibility mode, but not normal IE9 or Firefox 8. The issue is that the right div has content that normally wraps in the div, but in the modern browsers it pushes the right div down underneath the left div.

Comment: What is the policy on posting URLs? If possible, I can supply a link to illustrate my situation.

Comment: I have found my problem, there was another div in the right div that clears float and this was why it was misbehaving. Thanks for your help.

Comment: floating absolutely works in IE9 and FF 8. no prob for the help. good luck!